# Relative sequence / ack number in jNetPcap

Tags: java, networking, wireshark, jnetpcap

I've been tryind to get the relative sequence and ack numbers for some comparison, but i cannot seem to find a way to get the relative in jNetPcap? I can get the absolute value for both, but this that i am not interested in.

Anyone know how to retrieve the relatives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: talking about tcp?

Comment: @kaitoy yeah, tcp it is :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyze TCP sessions which start by SYN and end by FIN.

Firstly, collect TCP packets sent between a pair of endpoints (distinguished by an IP address and a port)

Then, divide them into sessions. A session starts with a TCP packet with `syn==true` and `ack=false`, and ends with two TCP packets with `fin=true` from client and server.

The client sequence number offset in a session is one plus the sequence number of the TCP packet with `syn==true` and `ack==false`.
The server sequence number offset in a session is one plus the sequence number of the TCP packet with `syn==true` and `ack==true`.
The client sequence number offset is the server ack number offset, and vice versa.

A relative number is absolute value minus offset.